# Generate truncated JSON using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

Given a .NET object, I would like to serialize it to a JSON string, but truncated to a specific length (e.g. 100 characters).

Is there an efficient way of doing that which does not involve serializing the entire object (which might be huge)?

---

Edited to make things clearer:

The result need not be a valid JSON string. It should be equivalent to:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj).Substring(0, 100);
```

... but without traversing the entire object graph.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether the resulting JSON is valid? If you have a class property, truncate its content. A lot of details are missing here, IMO.

Comment: Show us what you have try so far?

Comment: Mo, you need to provide more details about your problem. Right now it is too broad..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No serializer is going to *expect* this scenario, because usually their job is to make valid data that can be reliably parsed. However, many serializers have options to take a `TextWriter` (or if not that, then: a `Stream`) as an output target. You could write a custom subclass of those which either *silently discards* data after the chosen amount (although the serializer will still walk the entire object graph), or *deliberately throws an exception* once the desired amount has been reached (this exception would interrupt the serializer, allowing you to avoid most of the unnecessary work).